# Facebook Open Graph Image showing on web but not on Android app

Tags: android, facebook, image, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

Firstly, the images to accompany the following descriptions:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLrcB.jpg

I have created a custom Open Graph story for my app. The story is called **Record a Race**.
After I go through the flow in my app allowing the user to take a photo/choose one from their gallery, the user is brought into the Facebook app to complete the share process, as seen in **image 1**.

Once the user posts the share, it appears on their feed on facebook.com, as seen in **image 2**.

That same post appears without the image on the Facebook Android app, as seen in **image 3**.

Does anyone know if there is a way to cause the image to also appear on the mobile app? Or, is this just the way that Facebook handles this and there is nothing I can do?

Here is my FacebookDialog code:

```
OpenGraphObject course = OpenGraphObject.Factory.createForPost("myapp:race");
course.setTitle(race.getEventName());
course.setDescription(race.getRaceDetailsForFacebookShare());
course.setUrl("http://www.myappurl.com");
course.getData().setProperty("name", race.getEventName());
course.getData().setProperty("results", race.getResults());

GraphObject imageObject = GraphObject.Factory.create();
imageObject.setProperty("url", photoUri.toString());
imageObject.setProperty("user_generated", "true");

List<JSONObject> imagesList = Arrays.asList(imageObject.getInnerJSONObject());

OpenGraphAction action = OpenGraphAction.Factory.createForPost(OpenGraphAction.class, "myapp:record");
action.setProperty("race", course);
action.setImage(imagesList);

FacebookDialog fbDialog = new FacebookDialog.OpenGraphActionDialogBuilder(getActivity(), action, "race").setFragment(RaceDetailFragment.this).build();
uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(fbDialog.present());
```

*Thanks! And sorry for all of the image blurring!*

Comment: Did you add the proper permissions for the post such as the user_photos permission for this post? I think it's also better if you can post the permissions you've set though I'm no expert in this facebook api.

Comment: I did not add any permissions. It's my understanding that when using the Share Dialog approach to Facebook Open Graph sharing, you don't need to ask for any permissions nor add Facebook Login to your app. If anyone knows differently, I'd love to hear about it.

Comment: haha! Well I would love to hear about it as well but for what I see on [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share) it uses permissions. Hope someone can clarify this. :)